# How can I install a PyPI package while using Anaconda dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

When I install a package through `pip` (since it was not available on Anaconda), it also pulls all dependencies. It seems it will use the `pip` versions of the dependencies, even if `conda` versions (same name) are available.

How can I easily install a `pip` package, but use `conda` for the dependencies where such a package exists?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, I suspect. Create a virtual environment, install all anticipated dependencies using `conda` and then install the main package using `pip` without `-U/--upgrade`. `pip` seeing dependencies installed will not install them again.